# CMake find_package can't find my MinGW libjpeg

Tags: c, cmake, libjpeg

I get the error : Could NOT find JPEG (missing: JPEG_LIBRARY JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR)
when using

```
FIND_PACKAGE(JPEG REQUIRED)
IF(JPEG_FOUND)
  INCLUDE_DIRECTORIES(${JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR})
  TARGET_LINK_LIBRARIES(mpo ${JPEG_LIBRARIES})
ENDIF()
```

I have libjpeg installed under

```
C:\MinGW\
    |-lib\       for libjpeg.a
    |-include\   for jpeglib.h
```

Is there anything I missed ?
I'm using the **MSYS Makefiles** generator

Answer (score 2):

You need to make sure that CMake knows where to look for your libraries/headers. Some find modules provide a way to hint at where to look, it looks like FindJPEG.cmake does not.

1. You can specify the location of lib JPEG by specifying JPEG_LIBRARY and JPEG_INCLUDE_DIR via `-DJPEG_LIBRARY:PATH=C:/MinGW/lib/libjpeg.a -DJPEG_INCLUDE_DIR:PATH=C:/MinGW/include/` when you run cmake (or add these variables using the CMake GUI)
2. You can add C:\MinGW\lib and C:\MinGW\include to the relevant CMake environment variables (see http://www.cmake.org/Wiki/CMake_Useful_Variables#Environment_Variables)

Comment: I'll try this but I dont understand the point of giving the location of the libs to cmake while it detects everything else fine... Seems cmake aint as intelligent as i thought.. Even more useless when you have both mingw and vcc installed on your machine.

Comment: I would set the CMAKE_INCLUDE_PATH and CMAKE_LIBRARY_PATH envirnoment variables to those MinGW paths. If you do so, CMake will find all the things you have installed in MinGW without manual intervention.

Comment: But then when using visual studio generator it would look at the wrong path, maybe I would need to create my own libjpeg package finder. Atm I disabled the find package and let the user specify the location if it can't compile..

Answer (score 0):

I used this command: `cmake -DJPEG_LIBRARY_RELEASE=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/jpeg/9e/lib/libjpeg.a`

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).